# Using GETDATE() in a WHILE loop always returns the same value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, getdate

I understand [from sources like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847736/2704659) that [`GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should always (well, eventually, depending on how fast the loop is) return a different value in a loop.

I have this TSQL:

```
DECLARE @WaitUntilTime DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, 10, GETDATE())

WHILE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), @WaitUntilTime) > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT GETDATE(), @WaitUntilTime
END
```

But it's always outputting the same value for `GETDATE()`, and the loop never ends after 10 seconds like I want it to.  Why?

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620174/2704659) which sounds like a similar case, but it talks about `GETDATE()` being evaluated once for a column in a `SELECT` query.  I don't know if that applies to a while-loop as well.

By the way, I know about [`WAITFOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) but I can't use it because I want to introduce a delay within a single batch.

Comment: Your select is an implicit transaction unlike SET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @WaitUntilTime DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, 10, GETDATE())
DECLARE @Dummy int

WHILE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, GetDate(), @WaitUntilTime ) > 0)
BEGIN
    Set @Dummy=1
END
SELECT GetDate(), @WaitUntilTime
```

Returns after a 10 second delay

```
(No column name)        (No column name)
2016-10-18 13:53:20.000 2016-10-18 13:53:20.140
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!  Can you explain what is wrong with my way?  The question is really about *why* this is happening.

Comment: @rory.ap You stacked-up 10,072,069 SELECTS  .. changed dummy to a counter (just for fun)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- Still having trouble understanding -- is it because selects take a long time compared to var assignment, and it would eventually get to the end (after it ran through the 10M selects)?  Note, I had first tried something similar to your approach before I posted this question, but I had `SELECT 1` inside the loop.  I was looking for a no-op.  If my hypothesis is true (due to select overhead), the same explanation would apply, and I just shot myself in the foot by doing that.

Comment: @rory.ap The Select overhead was surprising.   I put your original select in place of the loop and and set the duration to 1 second.   It generated 176 selects in 12.362 seconds.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help, from one New Englander to another!

Comment: @rory.ap I keep telling my wife I belong in St. John's in the Virgin Islands.